# check a text file written has completed

Tags: bash, shell

My script has two part. first, it will execute a 2 java  class and write the output to 2 different text file and the output per file is large (10000 lines). second, after executing this command, it will start to read both of those file simultaneously and process it.

```
    java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.SMO  -t /Users/mainulquraishi/Documents/sentiment_directory/2014/Books/training/representation${i}_by_${i}.arff -no-cv -T /Users/mainulquraishi/Documents/sentiment_directory/2014/Books/representations/representation2014_by_${i}.arff  -v -o >>test1.txt 

   java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.SMO  -t /Users/mainulquraishi/Documents/sentiment_directory/2014/Books/training/representation${i}_by_${i}.arff -no-cv -T /Users/mainulquraishi/Documents/sentiment_directory/2014/Books/representations/representation2014_by_${i}.arff  -v -o >>test2.txt    

            while read compareFile1 <&3 && read compareFile2 <&4; do
              #Here the processing goes 
            done 3<test1.txt 4<test2.txt
```

Now, my question is, is there any possibility that before completing the writing of the both file, the second part of the program may start(both part is in the same program file)?
 if the answer is yes, how can i signal my program that the writing of both file has completed? or any other technique is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show the relevant parts of your script?

Comment: check the update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use process substitution, here a simplified example:

```
while read -d" " v1 <&3 && read -d" " v2 <&4; do
   echo "v1:$v1 v2:$v2";
done 3< <(echo "1 2 3 ") 4< <(echo "9 8 7 ")
```

Instead of the echo commands following the `<(`, use your output generating commands...

Note that the `-d" "` arguments to read is only needed to make read read space separated words rather than lines - just to keep the example small.

Comment: thanks for giving me new thought . What i understand from your code I replace  echo "1 2 3 " and echo "9 8 7 " those 2 echo with my 2 java command. is not it?

Comment: @MainulQuraishi: Yes, exactly.